# Cluster overload. How to avoid? Can I run separate h2o clusters? What additional technologies should I use?

Tags: python, h2o

I'm trying myself in creating a ML-based app. Server side in on python with the help of h2o, Client side is on nodejs + frontend.

The server side part has the next structure:
 - run.sh (script that takes parameters from client side and runs the needed python script)
 - preprocess.py
 - analyse.py
 - visualize.py
 - load.py
 - upload.py

Each script contains h20 cluster initialization:

```
h2o.init()
h2o.no_progress()
...  
...  
h2o.cluster().shutdown()  
exit(0)
```

It works fine if only one process is ran. If I start another process - I will soon face cluster overload since all the computations are stored inside the cluster on the machine with h2o.

Currently I tried to split processes via using Docker containers so that each script runs in separate docker container, but I'm starting to think that I chose the wrong way.

If there a way to split processes? Like running clusters on different ports for each call. So that shutting down of one process won't affect another running process.

Or maybe I should use some additional technologies?

Any advises are welcome.

Comment: if you specify the port number in h2o.init then you will be able to reach separate clusters.

Comment: @TomKraljevic yes, I read about such approach. But if I understood right, I can not specify which cluster to shut dowm, so I can't get whether it will close the "unneeded" cluster or not.

Comment: think of the h2o.init as setting the current cluster.  shutdown will shut the last one that was connected to.

Comment: or you can have multiple python interpreters, one for each cluster.